# Need help identifying this component on pcb

Tags: identification, components

[image]

Does anyone know what this component is?

Thanks

Comment: In general it is much easier to identify a component knowing the purpose of the circuit around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a [Light Dependent Resistor](https://www.google.com/search?q=LDR&sxsrf=ALeKk00IoWtzzQ1NauCSleA2Ev_mN1GJzQ:1582185256763&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinycqx09_nAhWG_qQKHURWDz0Q_AUoA3oECBEQBQ&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed an ldr, short for Light Dependent Resistor. Its resistance decreases when subjected to light and the resistance increases if the strength of the light is decreasing. Its resistance solely depends on the intensity of light.